# Form a key from encrypted component thales command

Tags: encryption, hsm

I am trying to form a key from encrypted components by sending a command to a thales hsm; the command is: Form a Key from Encrypted Components (A4) 

'HCONA42001UUF564A40B2E64C84233DFB1289B482496U30CDD5A92A3CACBA19496ECBD134C0E7'

and the response that i get is 'HCONA510' where the 10 indicates component parity error.
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because your HSM is not in authorized state.